# python - cannot remove duplicate entries on csv file

Tags: python-2.7, csv, duplicates

I have been working on this code, that reads files, in particular a csv file, removes all data after the delimiter character ';' .
The file contains numbers, and from those numbers I need to extract the duplicates. But, when I print the row extracted it is not seen as one number. 
I am a bit stuck, I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you and here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

# import module csv, for csv files
import csv

# Create a list 
hid = list()

# command prompt to enter file
fname = raw_input('Enter a file name: ')
# This is to hard code a file name to spare typing when testing, change the file name within ''.
if len(fname) == 0: fname = '20150909_0.csv'

# Define the variable to open file, and use from module csv, to read the csv file.
# alternative open --> fo = open(fname)
# and mycsv = csv.reader(open('20150909.csv'))
fo = csv.reader(open(fname))

# Initiate count 
count = 0
# Try to extract the duplicate:
#unique = 0
# Loop that reads, for each iteration (in this case the iteration is 'row', and 'fo' is the file), 
# each csv row, strips, the extra characters, and then splits them into a list by delimiter character ";"  
# and prints it
# To parse the data into a file, please type at cli "C:\python 'filename.py' > output.file
for row in fo:
    text = row[0]
    line = text.strip()
    parts = line.split(";")
    col1 = parts[0]
    print col1 

# Loop within the loop, for every word check if the word is in the list, else append it.
# then sort it.
    for parts in col1:
        if parts in hid: continue
        if parts != hid:
            hid.append(parts)


#       unique = unique + float(parts)


print "The total number of Hotel ID\'s entries is:", count
#print "The number of unique Hotel ID\'s is:", unique


for number in (int(hid) for L in lines):
    count = count + 1
    print count
```

Comment: could you also provide sample data you are trying to parse/process along with the code. It would make things easier to understand

Comment: 8555;0989;3245;5646;1212                                                                         8855;0989;3245;5646;1212                                                                         8555;0989;3245;5646;1212                                                                         8355;0989;3245;5646;1212  The above is an example of the entries. there are 4 lines and 4 rows. The row I want is the first (8555,8855,8555,8355) and want to remove the duplicates. I can't seem to find how to insert code in the comment,

Comment: Ok, I am still not able to get the data format , are you trying to say, your data has 4 rows and 4 columns and each column is delimited by ";" and you need the first column as list ?

Comment: you actually have that column in the first for loop , what you are trying to do in second for loop is wrong , instead of iterating over the 'parts' , you are trying to iterate over the first element of the parts list ('col1') and in the first 'if' clause you are trying to check if the entire parts list is in hid list , the second if clause would always yeild a True because you are comparing two different lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

# import module csv, for csv files
import csv

# Create a list 
hid = list()

# command prompt to enter file
fname = raw_input('Enter a file name: ')
# This is to hard code a file name to spare typing when testing, change the file name within ''.
if len(fname) == 0: fname = '20150909_0.csv'

# Define the variable to open file, and use from module csv, to read the csv file.
# alternative open --> fo = open(fname)
# and mycsv = csv.reader(open('20150909.csv'))
fo = csv.reader(open(fname))

# Initiate count 
count = 0
# Try to extract the duplicate:
#unique = 0
# Loop that reads, for each iteration (in this case the iteration is 'row', and 'fo' is the file), 
# each csv row, strips, the extra characters, and then splits them into a list by delimiter character ";"  
# and prints it
# To parse the data into a file, please type at cli "C:\python 'filename.py' > output.file
for row in fo:
    text = row[0]
    line = text.strip()
    parts = line.split(";")
    col1 = parts[0]
    # if you want only the first column do the processing here
    if col1 not in hid:
        hid.append(col1) 



print "The total number of Hotel ID\'s entries is:", count
print "The number of unique Hotel ID\'s is:", hid
```